# OpenSSL - rsa.h error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, visual-studio-6

I need to add SSL capability to an existing C++ socket client application.  I've downloaded and installed OpenSSL, and the appropriate libs and includes are in my Visual Studio folder.  Forgive the age of the dev environment (VC++ 6.0) but it's a legacy project, and only runs on Windows XP.

After adding this line:

```
// OpenSSL implementation for secure socket
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

To one of my header files, I now get this compile error:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\openssl\rsa.h(410) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\openssl\rsa.h(410) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\openssl\rsa.h(410) : fatal error C1004: unexpected end of file found
```

The line of the file causing the error is in rsa.h

```
int RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS(RSA *rsa, const unsigned char *mHash,          
            const EVP_MD *Hash, const unsigned char *EM, int sLen);
```

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to guess somewhere in your translation unit (that'd be the source file *and* all the `#include`s it includes, and that they include, etc..) you have a `#define` that is defining one of these symbols: `RSA`, `EVP_MD`, or `EM` as a macro constant. Eg: `#define RSA 1` .  Which one I leave to you to find. Just a guess mind you, but worth pursuing at least a little.

Comment: put lines before this include that says #define RSA xx #define mHash xx etc. Teh compiler will tell you if this is a repeated symbol declaration and where the conflicting define is

Comment: @Mangist - Whoz likely diagnosed it. You should re-arrange your headers. For example, include the Windows headers first, and then include the OpenSSL headers (or vice-versa).

Comment: OK thanks.  The only define I found out of those 3 was this one:   #define EM   (BYTE)0X19   it's in one of the serial comms header files.  How would I fix this so that the OpenSSL header is not conflicting?   (edit: I just commented out the #define, because it's just one of the ASCII codes and it's not used).  Thanks again everyone for your help)